# Creating A SQL Table From Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I create a table from a query, it seems like the table is only populated with data available from query at the time of creation. Is this correct?

If new data gets added to the dependent tables, then the created table wont sync with the updated data?

Is there anyway to make it so it always updates from the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

If you want the "table" to be automatically updated, then use a *view*.  This stores the query and runs it each time you reference it.

You can also create a [*materialized view*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html). This is like a view but it is usually faster.